# Symfony and Doctrine Unlink Associations

Tags: symfony, cakephp, doctrine

I am try to remove the associations on a entity ticket on run time just to reduce the size of the return array, I am new at Symfony I have been working previously on Cakephp there in Controller we use this 
    $this->User->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Friend')), true);

Is there any equalivant of unbindModel Available in Symfony

Comment: Did you try to use array hydration and ask doctrine only for specific fields? Otherwise you can use PARTIAL syntax in Doctrine query. But maybe you don't have data in this collection that you want to empty? Depending on the way you retrieve data, you may have your collection already empty until you ask for the data, for example with dumping it. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Are you aware of lazy loading? Associations are not loaded by Doctrine until you need them.

Comment: @JakubMatczak not really can you please give any tip or guideline?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html